# Problems with COLLATE in PostgreSQL 12

Tags: postgresql, collate

My problem:

I work in Windows 10 and my computer is set-up to Portuguese (pt_BR);

I'm building a database in PostgreSQL where I need certain columns to remain in Portuguese, but others to be in en_US - namely, those storing numbers and currency. I need $ instead of R$ and 1,000.00 instead of 1.000,00.

I tried to create columns this way using the COLLATE statement, as:

```
CREATE TABLE crm.TESTE (
    prodserv_id varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    prodserv_name varchar(140) NULL,
    fk_prodservs_rep_acronym varchar(4) NULL,
    prodserv_price numeric null collate "en_US",
    CONSTRAINT pk_prodservs_prodserv_id PRIMARY KEY (prodserv_id)
);
```

But I get the error message:

> SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: collation "en_US" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist

Database metadata shows Default Encoding: UTF8 and Collate Portuguese_Brazil.1252

It will be deployed at my ISP, which runs Linux.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first post here... why no paragraphs?

Comment: `collate` for a numeric column makes no sense at all

Answer (score 1):

A collation defines how *strings* are compared. It is not applicable to numerical data.

Moreover, PostgreSQL uses the operating system's collations, which causes problems when porting a database from Windows to other operating systems. The collation would be called `English` on Windows and `en_US.utf8` on operating systems that use glibc.

To influence the formatting of numbers and currency symbols, set the `lc_numeric` and `lc_monetary` parameters appropriately (`English` on Windows, `en_US` elsewhere). Note that while `lc_monetary` affects the string representation of the `money` data type, these settings do not influence the string representation of numbers. You need to use `to_char` like this:

```
to_char(1000, '999G999G999D00 L');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems the problem was that I used en_US instead of English.
Thank you for your kind and prompt response.